# Using listView and spinner in 1 layout

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner, android-cursoradapter

I use listview with cursor adapter and spinner in 1 layout. 
I don't know how to use setAdapter into these 2 different thing.

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_layou, R.id.txt, item);
//sp.setAdapter(adapter); <----- I should have to set my spinner adapter here, but it seems to make it crash 

cursorAdapter = new NotesCursorAdapter(this, null, 0); //my own class which extend CursorAdapter

ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

I have google it and find some clue by using `ArrayAdapter`. But what i found is `ArrayAdapter` used for the same type adapter (in my case, I use 2 different adapter(`Spinner` and `CursorAdapter`) CMIIW. Is anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Add your crash log. Wat error you got while executing.

Comment: Please post the code of both adapters.

Comment: I got no crash log on my android studio. The application is just stopped.
I wonder if I can set 2 different adapter in the same layout. The code I post above is written in the onCreate method on main_activity.

Comment: Yes you can use multiple adapter in same layout. But probably you got any error while application just stopped.

Comment: Hello @MohamedMohaideenAH, Yes, i was forgot to set my code inside my spinnerAdapter. Thank for your support guys.